# используя PHP собрать информацию из SPAN внутри конкретного DIV

Tags: php, html, span

как из PHP собрать содержимое всех тегов span(текст между ними) , которые находятся внутри div с определенным id ?

Comment: Теоретически, сначала найти соответствия для div.id, а после - вытащить из span значения. Я уже не за ПК, так что до завтра примеров не напишу.

Answer (score 2):

> *Как собрать содержимое всех тегов span, которые находятся внутри div с определенным id ?*

Теоретически, сначала найти соответствия для div.id, а после - вытащить из span значения. Пример для `div`, у которого `id` равен `"a"`:

```
$str = '
    <div id="b">
        <span>Этот текст игнорируется</span>
        <span>Этот текст игнорируется</span>
    </div>

    <div id="a">
        <span>Выбрать этот текст 1.1</span>
        <span>И этот текст тоже 1.2</span>
    </div>

    <div id="b">
        <span>Этот текст игнорируется</span>
        <span>Этот текст игнорируется</span>
    </div>

    <div id="a">
        <span>Выбрать этот текст 2.1</span>
        <span>И этот текст тоже 2.2</span>
    </div>
';

$span = [];

preg_replace_callback(
    '~<div id="a">(.+?)</div>~s', function($m)use(&$span){
        preg_match_all('~<span[^>]*>(.+?)</span>~s', $m[1], $a);        
        array_map(function($s)use(&$span){ $span[] = $s; }, $a[1]);
    }, $str
);

var_dump($span);
```

Результат:

```
array {
  0 => 'Выбрать этот текст 1.1'
  1 => 'И этот текст тоже 1.2'
  2 => 'Выбрать этот текст 2.1'
  3 => 'И этот текст тоже 2.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated:

Вариант 1

```
<?php

$html = '
<div id="content">
    <div class="foo">
        <span class="bar">Text 1</span>
        <span>Text 2</span>
        <span>Text 3</span>
    </div>
</div>';

// ID тега
$tagID = 'content';

// регуляркой берем содержимое необходимого блока
preg_match('/<div[^>]*id="'.$tagID.'">(.*?)<\\/div>/si', $html, $matches);
if ($matches) {
    // Перебираем все теги span
    if (preg_match_all('#<span[^>]*>(.*?)</span>#si', $matches[1], $matchesItems)) {
        foreach ($matchesItems[1] as $item) {
            // Извлекаем построчно
            echo $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Вариант 2

```
$html = '
<html>
<div id="content">
eee
    <div class="foo">
        <span class="bar">Text 1e</span>
        <span>Text 2</span>
        <span>Text 3</span>
    </div>
</div>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->getElementById('content');

$nodes = $div->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach ($nodes as $item) {
    echo $item->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: А как получить выборку дерева DOM , если страничка на которой находятся эти span динамически обновляется, т е в исходном файле их ещё нет, как выбрать только часть такой страницы , чтобы не выбирать всё, только содержимое этого конкретного div c конкретным id?

Comment: Обновил код, посмотри